# Why do we use the 'virtual' keyword (etymologically)?

Tags: language-agnostic, virtual

Most modifiers make sense to me - abstract, protected etc. But "virtual" seems a confusing arbitrary choice for what is really "overridable".

'Virtual' in computing (virtual machine, virtual memory) seems to mean an abstract representation of something. I guess this originated from optics, where a virtual image (usually in**vert**ed) itself comes from Medieval Latin virtuālis, meaning "effective".

So it seems to me it would make more sense if the 'virtual' method in computing was the overriding one, not the one-to-be-overriden.

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental about 'virtual', can anyone shed any more light on why it was chosen?

Comment: +1 This is an excellent question.  I am really curious to learn the result.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more fitting on Programmers.SE?

Comment: A note for the curious: the root of virtual (virtūs, virtue) has nothing to do with invert (vertere, to turn).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tend to think of the term "virtual" as meaning not real. Such as, in terms of virtual memory, that maps *through* to real memory at some point but is really a placeholder until the mapping is needed.

Similarly, a virtual function is a placeholder which maps through to a real function at some point.

Even if you use the (somewhat childish) "pretend" definition, it makes sense:

```
virtual/pretend machine
virtual/pretend memory
virtual/pretend function
```

In all those cases, the "virtual" is something that isn't real. The use of them is translated into something real (emulating the machine, mapping the memory addresses through an MMU, calling a class-specific *actual* function rather than the virtual one, and so on).

Comment: Thanks. But that really only makes sense if you see virtual in the same way as abstract; that is, something you _expect_ to be overridden. In which case you'd make it abstract to start off with! In your example with memory, the analogy with programming would be that the the virtual memory 'overrides' the real memory. But in programming, we call the _real_ thing 'virtual', which is the _opposite_ of what I would expect.

Comment: Let me clarify what I meant. I think your description is right but, from my POV, you have the real/virtual mixed up. My view is that the function in the _base_ class is virtual because, when it comes time to call it, it will actually map through to the real function, the one in the derived class (assuming the class has been derived from, of course).

Answer (score 1):

When you say,

> "virtual" seems a confusing arbitrary choice for what is really "overridable"

I agree that 'overridable' might be a better keyword, but I don't think 'virtual' is arbitrary. I think there's a good, historically plausible reason for using it.

Some example C++:

```
class C {
    virtual int x() { ... }
    ...
}

C *cp;

...

cp->x();
```

`cp->x()` will call real code, so I don't think `abstract` is the right word.
But which code will it call? Just because `cp` is a pointer to `C` doesn't mean it
couldn't be pointing to something that *inherits* from `C`.

See, the *call* is virtualized. Just like virtual memory addresses are mapped
to real memory addresses, virtual function calls are mapped to real functions
calls, via the virtual method table.

According to Google, virtual means, "Almost or nearly as described, but not completely or according to strict definition". I think that's a pretty decent adjective, considering that a virtual method call is almost like a real method call, except for some redirection.

Now, imagine when virtual method calls are a brand new idea. You could imagine
that, in all the heady excitement of creating a new language that has them
*built right in* (!!!), one would be naturally drawn to using that keyword.

Poor `C::x()` is an innocent bystander in all this excitement. Using the
`virtual` keyword tells the compiler that calls to the method will be virtualized, but clearly there's nothing 'virtual' or 'abstract'
about `C::x()` itself. It's just the poor sucker who gets stuck being the default
method in the method table.

Now this is just conjecture, but perhaps there's a reason that C++ uses the term
"pure virtual" to describe a method that *has* to overridden. Maybe concrete
objects of type `C` don't use virtual method calls, even for "virtual" methods.
Pure virtual methods, of course, would *always* have to be called through a
virtual method table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following line of code:

```
base.Method();
```

Where base is an instantiation of Base or one of its child classes.

If Method() is a virtual method, then we are not directly calling the function Method(). Instead we are "redirected" to the actual function, depending on what base is.

So the word 'virtual' isn't attempting to describe the function itself which is declared in the base class. It actually describes the fact the we want to abstract the calling of the function.

Comment: Surely if we wanted to abstract the calling of the function, we'd describe it as abstract in the first place? The use of that keyword makes sense to me. But by describing it as 'virtual', that implies the opposite of what it is, which is the _real_ function that is available to be abstracted if you want. So it would make more sense to call the derived method virtual.